# Assign Active Entitlement Process to Entitlement

Tags: entitlements

How to automate the assigning of "Active" and latest version of "Entitlement Processes"  to Entitlements?

I cannot write trigger on Entitlement Process so that whenever a new Version is updated I could assign it to Entitlements.

Comment: https://salesforce.art.blog/2019/09/15/entitlement-management-entitlement-processes-milestone/
find interesting stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay!! Fortunate enough to find this link today!

**Step by Step Process:**

[Using New Versions of Entitlement Processes](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=entitlements_process_using_new_versions.htm&language=en_US)

**Video Tutorial:**

[UPDATING ENTITLEMENT PROCESSES WITH ENTITLEMENT VERSIONING](http://www.salesforce.com/_app/video/Service_Cloud/help/Upgrading_Entitlement_Processes_New_Version/)

Comment: https://salesforce.art.blog/2019/09/15/entitlement-management-entitlement-processes-milestone/